# while setting up virtualenv cannot use apt get. even after checking owner permissions

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

having set up virtualenv, im trying to install easy_install.

I created env without sudo: 
permissions check out as local user. but it still wont let me install anything.

```
(py33)loenja@loenja-VirtualBox:~$ ls -ld virt_env/py33
drwxr-xr-x 4 loenja loenja 4096 Dec 21 01:33 virt_env/py33
```

this is the error i get.  and restart has no effect

```
(py33)loenja@loenja-VirtualBox:~$ apt-get install python3.3
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
(py33)loenja@loenja-VirtualBox:~$
```

what have I been doing wrong?.

command used to create env was:

```
loenja@loenja-VirtualBox:~$ virtualenv -p python3.3 virt_env/py33
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in virt_env/py33/bin/python3.3
Not overwriting existing python script virt_env/py33/bin/python (you must use virt_env/py33/bin/python3.3)
Installing     Setuptools.............................................................................................done.
Installing    Pip....................................................................................................................................done.
```

oh yeh im running xubuntu on virtualbox

edit in response to comments:
creating n env without any arguments results in this:
    (default)loenja@loenja-VirtualBox:~$ python --version
    Python 2.7.5+

in env py33 i have 3.3:
    loenja@loenja-VirtualBox:~$ source virt_env/py33/bin/activate
    (py33)loenja@loenja-VirtualBox:~$ python --version
    Python 3.3.2+

Comment: The virtualenv command already has `3.3`, why are you trying to install it again? Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: by default it was running 2.7, I need the default interpreter to be 3.x. after that i need to install openopt among other libraries

Comment: So if you activate the virtualenv and do `python --version`, it doesn't say 3.3? What do you get when you do `which python` in the env?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get install` has nothing to do with `virtualenv`. If you needed `sudo apt-get install` before you created `virtualenv`; you need `sudo` now as well. `virtualenv` is about Python packages. `apt-get` deals with different kind of packages.

To install a python package inside an active virtualenv, you could use `pip` which is installed by default when you've created the `virtualenv`. You don't need `sudo` to use `pip`.